# Windows Phone InputScope - all languages

Tags: windows-phone-8, keyboard

I need in my keyboard all European language letters (German, Spanish, French etc...) For now my keybord has values only for my region country.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot influence the keyboard layout from your app.